# Picture inserted in the post not showing in "Gallery"

Tags: post-thumbnails, gallery

I have some posts in which I inserted the picture manually (before migrating to Worpdress)

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/2010/quand-l-inde-compte-ses-habitants,M35788.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
```

I want to use those pictures as "featured image", but they don't appear in the post Gallery. What is the best way to "import" them, knowing that they already are on my server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution - using the plugin "Add from server", I can re-import the pictures which I attached to the posts when the blog was powered by Dotclear.